# Does Rouché's theorem work in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

I think if Rouché's theorem ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem)) works in real analysis, then maybe we can give a simple proof of the invariant domain theorem ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)).

Comment: What would it mean for Rouche's theorem to work in real analysis?

Comment: Even if we are only trying to prove the invariant domain theorem for $\mathbb{R}^2$, I don't see any reasonable way to proceed. Rouche's theorem is only for analytic function (which are always open maps) and in general are very rarely injective (for examples try to classify all injective entire functions, it is a very small class of functions), and invariant domain theorem deals with arbitrary injective continuous functions.

Comment: @OwenSizemore not all analytic functions are open (only all non constant analytic functions are open)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Ok sure, but besides this trivial case....

Answer (score 4):

Rouché's Theorem *is* a special case of a general theorem in differential topology. Suppose $W$ is an oriented, compact $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary and $f\colon W\to\mathbb R^n$ is a smooth map with the property that $f$ omits the value $0$ on $\partial W$ and $0$ is a regular value of $f$ on the interior of $W$, then the degree of $f/|f|\colon\partial W\to S^{n-1}$ gives the number of zeroes of $f$ in the interior, counted with algebraic multiplicities.

This can be applied to two functions $f$ and $g$ as in Rouché, because the hypotheses of Rouché dictate that $f/|f|$ and $(f+g)/|f+g|$ have the same degree on $\partial W$.